# grep doesn't print matches

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to print all root accesing attempts from /var/log/auth.log with grep. But it seems like grep isn't processing the whole file, instead grep is stopping at some point:

```
> less /var/log/auth.log | grep Accepted
Apr 10 08:32:43 sshd[16845]: Accepted password for root from ... port 49061 ssh2
Apr 10 09:42:38 sshd[15451]: Accepted password for root from ... port 48990 ssh2
Apr 10 10:11:17 sshd[21592]: Accepted password for root from ... port 48686 ssh2
Apr 10 12:09:03 sshd[5757]: Accepted password for root from ... port 62535 ssh2
Apr 11 18:12:12 sshd[1804]: Accepted password for root from ... port 40765 ssh2
Apr 11 18:12:30 sshd[1884]: Accepted password for root from ... port 40808 ssh2
Apr 11 18:13:46 sshd[2063]: Accepted password for root from ... port 40735 ssh2
Apr 11 19:58:44 sshd[17103]: Accepted password for root from ... port 40684 ssh2
Apr 11 20:48:06 sshd[24583]: Accepted password for root from ... port 40466 ssh2
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

As we can see, there are only entries until the Apr 11th. So if I try the following command:

```
> less /var/log/auth.log | grep "Apr 12"
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Nothing gets printed. But in the file /var/log/auth.log the "Apr 12" entries are present as we can see if I run this command (I also proved it by printing the whole file with cat):

```
> less /var/log/auth.log | grep -c "Apr 12"
4297
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong with my first grep command.

Comment: Why are you using less?  Just `grep "Apr 12" /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Sounds like you have some non-ASCII data in the log.

Comment: @Jesse_b I know, I was playing arround for testing purporses :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To force `grep` to treat files with binary content as ASCII, use its `-a` flag:

```
grep -a 'Apr 12' /var/log/auth.log
```

This is a non-standard option but is implemented in GNU `grep` and in the `grep` on OpenBSD (and probably the other BSD's as well).

When the data that is processed by GNU `grep` contains nul bytes, or when it is improperly encoded for the current locale, `grep` will treat it as binary.  With `-a` or `--binary-files=text`, GNU `grep` will be forced to treat such data as text.  See the documentation for the `--binary-files` option in the GNU `grep` manual.

`grep` normally refuses to output binary data as it may have "have nasty side effects if the output is a terminal and if the
              terminal driver interprets some of it as commands." (quote from the manual).

Comment: Thanks first, your hint solved my problem. What's graps beheavior in case of binary content is present? How grep notice there is binary data present?

Comment: @JulianH See updated answer.